# LoRA Fine-Tuning on CPU Error: Using `load_in_8bit=True` requires Accelerate

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I'm trying to follow the instructions from the great blog post [Efficient Large Language Model training with LoRA and Hugging Face](https://www.philschmid.de/fine-tune-flan-t5-peft) to fine-tune a small model via LoRA. To prepare as much as possible, I'm trying to run everything locally via CPU first.

When running 'AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained' I get the following error:

> ImportError: Using `load_in_8bit=True` requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate` and the latest version of bitsandbytes `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes` or pip install bitsandbytes`

I've tried various ways to import accelerate and bitsandbytes but without success. The fine-tuning code without LoRA works ([Fine-tune FLAN-T5 for chat & dialogue summarization](https://www.philschmid.de/fine-tune-flan-t5-peft)). That one doesn't use accelerate.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Or is accelerate not supported on CPU?

Here is what I've tried:

```
!pip install "peft"
!pip install "transformers" "datasets" "accelerate" "evaluate" "bitsandbytes" loralib --upgrade --quiet
or
!pip install "peft==0.2.0"
!pip install "transformers==4.27.2" "datasets==2.9.0" "accelerate==0.17.1" "evaluate==0.4.0" "bitsandbytes==0.37.1" loralib --upgrade --quiet
or
!pip install -q -U bitsandbytes
!pip install -q -U git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git 
!pip install -q -U git+https://github.com/huggingface/peft.git
!pip install -q -U git+https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate.git
```

Update Nov 27th: I get the same error when running on a V100 GPU.

Comment: Can you please post all parameters you are using with `from_pretrained`? Have you tried to install accelerate first before importing anything from transformers?

Comment: AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_id, load_in_8bit=True, device_map="auto")

Comment: Thanks @cronoik. I use the exact code from the referenced blog. The only things I've changed are the different ways to import the dependencies. I also tried installing accelerate first.

Answer (score 0):

This works now:

```
pip install "accelerate==0.17.1"
pip install "peft==0.2.0"
pip install "transformers==4.27.2" "datasets" "evaluate==0.4.0" "bitsandbytes==0.41.2.post2" loralib
pip install rouge-score tensorboard py7zr scipy
```